# How to create Standard Logic App using Rest api?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template, azure-workflow-automation

Using the official documentation [Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/), i'm able to create and work with `Consumption Logic Apps`. Is it possible to create `Standard Logic App` using Rest API in similar way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer, as it currently stands and looks to be, is **no**.

As per the documentation ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/single-tenant-overview-compare#create-build-and-deploy-options

There are currently limited options for a standard logic app.

**Standard**

[image: Standard]

**Consumption**

[image: Consumption]

### Update

Standard logic apps now have additional ways to deploy, still not the full suite but it's grown.

[image: Update]

Comment: As @Skin said, there no APIs available for standard Logic app however for some operations like retrieving data we can use some APIs from browser traces, refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/728918/is-there-a-workflow-rest-api-for-logic-app-standar.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is tecnically possible but you need to rethink the definition.

Logic App Standard (aka. Single-Tenant Logic App) is built on top of the function runtime and the infrastructure is seperated from the actual workflow definition. Deployment to the resource basically works the same way as for Function Apps.

1. Deploy the infrastructure
2. Deploy the workflow (function for function apps).

More on that here: [DevOps deployment for single-tenant Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/devops-deployment-single-tenant-azure-logic-apps#separate-concerns)

For your case you would:

1. Deploy the infrastructure via the REST API

   - Storage account
   - Server Farm (App Service Plan)
   - Site (App Service)
2. Build the Logic App Standard project and create a zip archive.
3. Deploy the archive using zip deployment via REST API.

   - This sounds easy but requires more work, see links below.

Links:

- [Set up DevOps deployment for Standard logic app workflows in single-tenant Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/set-up-devops-deployment-single-tenant-azure-logic-apps?tabs=github)
- [Deploy ZIP file with REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push#rest)