# How to Convert the logicapp plan from consumption to Standard by using azure devops?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to convert logicapp plans using Azure DevOps pipelines in our organization but I didn't find any option to run the task in ADO. Any suggestions Please.

Comment: See this answer ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72008546/how-to-create-standard-logic-app-using-rest-api/72008837#72008837

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As of now as per this [**Microsoft Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/single-tenant-overview-compare#create-build-and-deploy-options). Azure Devops is not supporting Logic APP standard plan. So, we can't convert consumption to standard plan.

[image]

You can raise a [**Feature Request**](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/search?space=21) that will help the other community members who want to use this feature.

Comment: Can we deploy/automate the Standard logicapp using ARM templates through ADO pipelines ? @SaiSakethGuduru-MT

Comment: Yes, @Ramgopal: We can do it out by creating a task (Azure Resource Group deployment) in the release pipeline as described in this document. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-deploy-azure-resource-manager-templates#deploy-with-azure-devops

Comment: I can create consumption type logic apps with sample workflow using ARM templates. I want to create standard type logic apps with sample workflows using ARM templates.

Comment: @Ramgopal: Check this link which gives information about Standard logic app deployment.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/set-up-devops-deployment-single-tenant-azure-logic-apps?tabs=github

Comment: Also, if you got the resolution to your problem could you please accept that as an answer so that it would be helpful for other community members who has similar kind of issues

Comment: Hey Ramgopal, had it solved your problem else you can share more details so I can troubleshoot?