# How to create an Azure logic app with a standard plan using azure-sdk-python

Tags: python, azure-logic-apps, azure-automation, azure-sdk-python

I am trying to automate my logic app creation process using azure-sdk-for-python.

Here's my python script.

```
import schedule
import time
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.logic import LogicManagementClient

def create_logic_app(iteration):
    subscription_id = ''  # replace with your Azure subscription ID
    resource_group_name = ''  # replace with your resource group name
    logic_app_name = f'Twa_{iteration}'  # Unique name for each Logic App
    location = 'East US'  # Azure region

    credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
    resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)
    logic_client = LogicManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)
 
    print("Creating/Updating resource group...")
    resource_client.resource_groups.create_or_update(resource_group_name, {'location': location})

    logic_app_parameters = {
        'location': location,
        "properties": {
            "definition": {
                "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
                "actions": {
                    "Compose": {
                        "inputs": "Insert logic",
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "Compose"
                    }
                },
                "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                "outputs": {},
                "triggers": {
                    "Recurrence": {
                        "recurrence": {
                            "frequency": "Minute",
                            "interval": 3
                        },
                        "type": "Recurrence"
                    }
                }
            },
            "kind": "Stateful"
        }
            # Additional parameters here
    }


    print(f"Creating/Updating Logic App: {logic_app_name}...")
    logic_client.workflows.create_or_update(resource_group_name, logic_app_name, logic_app_parameters)
    
    print(f"Logic App {logic_app_name} created/updated successfully.")

def job():
    for i in range(10):
        create_logic_app(i)

create_logic_app("recurrence")
```

The current script is creating logic apps with a plan-type: consumption. I want to create logic apps with a Plan-type: Standard.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: This answer is old but the link to the approaches MS provides is still current … https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72008546/how-to-create-standard-logic-app-using-rest-api/72008837#72008837 … and in basic terms, I don’t think it’s possible using the SDK, you’d need to use REST calls.

Comment: @Skin Could you give a hint or a resource on how to use the REST Calls. 
I've used the CLI  command  given by {venkatesan} and it is successfully creating the Standard Logic App, now the main challenge is that how we create workflows in it. 
If I could use REST Calls for the same that would be a great help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The current script is creating logic apps with a plan-type: consumption. I want to create logic apps with a Plan-type: Standard.

I agree with Skin's comment, it may not be possible to use the SDK, so you’d need to use **`REST calls`** or **`Azure CLI`** commands to create a standard plan type.

You can refer to this **[MS-document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/single-tenant-overview-compare#create-build-and-deploy-options)**. As of now, you can use the Azure CLI commands is an easy way to create logic apps with standard plan type.

**Command:**

```
az logicapp create -g <your-resource-group> --subscription <your-subscription-id> -p "<plan name or resource Id of app service plan>" -n myLogicApp3261 -s <storage account name>
```

**Output:**

```
PS /home/xxx> az logicapp create -g <your-resource-group> --subscription <your-subscription-id> -p "<plan name or resource Id of app service plan>" -n myLogicApp3261 -s <storage account name>
Application Insights "myLogicApp3261" was 
{
  "availabilityState": "Normal",
  "clientAffinityEnabled": false,
  "clientCertEnabled": false,
  "clientCertExclusionPaths": null,
  "clientCertMode": "Required",
  "cloningInfo": null,
  "containerSize": 1536,
  "customDomainVerificationId": "A18xxxx0034F7C3E60zzzzzzz3",
  "dailyMemoryTimeQuota": 0,
  "defaultHostName": "mylogicapp3261.azurewebsites.net",
  "enabled": true,
  "enabledHostNames": [
    "mylogicapp3261.azurewebsites.net",
    "mylogicapp3261.scm.azurewebsites.net"
  ],
```

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[az logicapp | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/logicapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-logicapp-create-examples)